# How do I start a page with a function always in C# xamarin forms android?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to start a Page using a function always. How could I do that? Because the first time works perfectly but the second it does't work.

Here is some content about my app.

1. homePage
2. ScanQRPage

So, basically I have a button in homePage that redirect to ScanQRPage. And there I have this constructor

```
public ScanQRPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnScannerQR.IsVisible = true;
        Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += ConnectivityChangedHandler;

        Scanner();
    }
```

And what I need is that every time the user go to this page (ScanQRPage), the Scanner function start.

How could I do that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `OnAppearing`

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    Scanner();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It gives me this error but i cannot modify the file from protected to public. any idea? 'ScanQRPage.OnAppearing()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member 'Page.OnAppearing()'

Comment: my mistake, it should be `protected`